# fetch data from two tables with single query

Tags: sql

Have two tables say ABC and XYZ and contain one column which data will be unique across these table. Now I have id with me but don't know in which table this id belongs. Is it possible to fetch record in single query with that id from ABC or XYZ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you share the table schema you have, we will be able to answer your question much more aptly.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer in your Q?  
Are you looking for a row with  a specific ID in one of the 2 tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to fetch record in single query with that id from ABC
>   or XYZ?

Yes, you can use `UNION`(implicit distinct) or `UNION ALL`(with duplicate values) to get all id's from the two tables:

```
SELECT id FROM ABC
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM XYZ
```